# Sorting Out data based on Date and event status with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataset from which I want to find out hour wise how many providers were online each day.The dataframe looks like this -

```
                          provider_id        event_time   final_status  rank
325  0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b 2017-09-04 08:00:19       online     1
326  0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b 2017-09-04 08:29:39       online     2
327  0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b 2017-09-04 08:44:36      offline     3
328  0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b 2017-09-04 09:06:12       online     4
330  0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b 2017-09-04 12:23:24       online     5
331  0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b 2017-09-04 12:23:47      offline     6
332  0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b 2017-09-04 12:45:46       online     7
333  0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b 2017-09-04 12:45:56      offline     8
334  0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b 2017-09-04 17:38:31       online     9
335  0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b 2017-09-04 17:40:51       online    10
```

and the sample output will be something like this. Here, if we look at the first 3 rows, we can see the provider was online from `2017-09-04 08:00:19` to `2017-09-04 08:44:36`. and then he was offline till `2017-09-04 09:06:12` and then continued to online till `2017-09-04 12:23:24` . That's how the rest of the `seconds_online` values are calculated.

```
                      provider_id         day        start_hour  end_hour  seconds_online  
0   0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b  2017-09-04           8         9      2657
1   0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b  2017-09-04           9        10      3228 
2   0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b  2017-09-04          10        11      3600
3   0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b  2017-09-04          11        12      3600
4   0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b  2017-09-04          12        13      2746
5   0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b  2017-09-04          13        14      10
6   0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b  2017-09-04          14        15      0
7   0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b  2017-09-04          15        16      0
8   0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b  2017-09-04          16        17      0
9   0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b  2017-09-04          17        18      140
10  0037dfffff8b03bbdf366a263735e84b  2017-09-04          18        19      0
```

With `for loop`, it is quite easy but the dataset currently having more than 20 million rows. Using `for` isn't an optimized solution. It is showing, it will take around 7 days time. Can anyone please help here ??

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, df is pandas dataframe.

```
df = df.sort(['Date', 'event status'], ascending=[True, False])
```

Comment: how do we calculate the ```seconds_online``` column from your code? For user wise and day wise ranking already implemented by me.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. Here are some thoughts, no complete solution, but maybe parts of it are useful.

I wasn't able to do it without for-looping, which is a shame. My strategy was therefore to reduce the number of loops. To that end I did some preprocessing.

The first step is getting rid of unnecessary "online rows":

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df['start'] = ((df.final_status.eq('online'))
               & (df.final_status.shift(1).isin(['offline', np.NaN])))
df['end'] = (((df.final_status.eq('offline'))
              & (df.final_status.shift(1).eq('online')))
             | (df.final_status.shift(-1).isna()))
df = df[df.start != df.end].drop(columns=['final_status', 'start'])
```

Result (I don't show the columns which aren't relevant):

```
           event_time    end
0 2017-09-04 08:00:19  False
2 2017-09-04 08:44:36   True
3 2017-09-04 09:06:12  False
5 2017-09-04 12:23:47   True
6 2017-09-04 12:45:46  False
7 2017-09-04 12:45:56   True
8 2017-09-04 17:38:31  False
9 2017-09-04 17:40:51   True
```

Based on the result I'm then forming intervals:

```
df = pd.concat([df.event_time[df.end.eq(value)].reset_index(drop=True)
                for value in (False, True)],
               ignore_index=True,
               axis='columns').rename(columns={0: 'start', 1: 'end'})
```

Result:

```
                start                 end
0 2017-09-04 08:00:19 2017-09-04 08:44:36
1 2017-09-04 09:06:12 2017-09-04 12:23:47
2 2017-09-04 12:45:46 2017-09-04 12:45:56
3 2017-09-04 17:38:31 2017-09-04 17:40:51
```

And as step two the for-looping, now over far less rows:

```
idx = pd.date_range(df.start.min().floor('H'), df.end.max().floor('H'), freq='H')
df_secs = pd.DataFrame({'secs': 0}, index=idx)
df_secs.index.name = 'hours'
for s, e in zip(df.start, df.end):
    if s.hour == e.hour:
        df_secs.loc[s.floor('H'), 'secs'] += (e - s).seconds
    else:
        df_secs.loc[s.floor('H'), 'secs'] += (s.ceil('H') - s).seconds
        hrs = pd.date_range(s.ceil('H'), e.floor('H'), freq='H', closed='left')
        df_secs.loc[hrs, 'secs'] += 3600
        df_secs.loc[e.floor('H'), 'secs'] += (e - e.floor('H')).seconds
```

Result (`print(df_secs)`):

```
                     secs
hours                    
2017-09-04 08:00:00  2657
2017-09-04 09:00:00  3228
2017-09-04 10:00:00  3600
2017-09-04 11:00:00  3600
2017-09-04 12:00:00  1437
2017-09-04 13:00:00     0
2017-09-04 14:00:00     0
2017-09-04 15:00:00     0
2017-09-04 16:00:00     0
2017-09-04 17:00:00   140
```

I wasn't able to figure out why you have `2746` for `start_hour == 12` and `10` for `start_hour == 13`? I can't see how that is compatible with the example data you provided. For example at `12:45:56` the status is `offline` and the next `online` status is at `17:38:31`, so there shouldn't be any seconds for `start_hour == 13`?

As I said, this is not a complete solution: I guess you have many `provider_id`s, which would require an outer `groupby` loop, etc.